# i have a probleme when i wan create a new project react with cmd npm init react-app my-app

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

C:\Users\lenovo>npm init react-app preparefm
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-30T22_32_20_187Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use [vite](https://vitejs.dev/). it's way better than create-react-app

just type :

> npm create vite@latest

then choose your app name, Select a framework, and then cd to your app and install the required modules by executing:

> npm i

Comment: I found the issue I just edited my npm config file and set  https-proxy to = null